# WPF 'instances' surviving behind the curtain?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Window subclass. The window contains an ItemsControl, which's ItemsSource gets initialized in the Window subclass ctor. The window is shown using ShowDialog(), on a new instance each time. The thing I am seeing is that even though the window and the ItemsControl are new instances each time they're shown, the IEnumerable assigned to the ItemsSource somehow gets remembered (it seems), and thus GetEnumerator() isn't called each time the window is shown, so changes aren't reflected. This does not happen all the time, though, sometimes GetEnumerator() is actually invoked. If I assign a new IEnumerable to ItemsSource each time, GetEnumerator is always called.

Is there some sort of weird caching going on behind the scenes, or perhaps an underlying instance to the ItemsControl that is (often) reused (possibly affected by garbage collection) ?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BalticWpfControlLib.SystemInfoWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BalticWpfControlLib"
        Title="System Information" Height="400" Width="300"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" >
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl Name="MaintenanceInfos">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="4,4,4,0" BorderBrush="Gray">
                        <local:MaintenanceInfoUserControl Margin="0,0,0,4"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class SystemInfoWindow : Window
{
    public SystemInfoWindow(IEnumerable<IMaintenanceInfo> maintenanceInfos)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ItemsControl instance={0}", System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(MaintenanceInfos));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(null == MaintenanceInfos.ItemsSource);

        MaintenanceInfos.ItemsSource = maintenanceInfos;
    }
}
```

Code for showing dialog:

```
private void ShowSysInfo_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    var dlg = new SystemInfoWindow(facade.MaintenanceInfos);
    dlg.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
    dlg.ShowDialog();
}
```

`facade.MaintenanceInfos` is a property always returning the same `IEnumerable<IMaintenanceInfo>` instance.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: Is the `IEnumerable` a new instance for each dialog, or do multiple dialog instances share the same instance of the `Enumerable`?

Comment: The `IEnumerable` is the same each time the dialog is shown, but it could possibly enumerate different items. If the `IEnumerable`is a new instance, `GetEnumerator()` is invoked each time as expected - I just don't understand how it 'remembers' the `IEnumerable`...

Comment: Why do you have a WPF Window subclass?  Do you mean `MainWindow.xaml.cs`?

Comment: @hooverphonique is your IEnumerable `static`?

Comment: @JonathanCarroll code now added..

Comment: @NETscape code now added which hopefully answers your questions..

Comment: `always returning the same IEnumerable<IMaintenanceInfo> instance` - what's the *actual* type of this enumerable? are you sure it's not array or something else that stores items internally?

Comment: The posted code looks solid, so I'm guessing the ghost is in facade.MaintenanceInfos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
MaintenanceInfos.ItemsSource = maintenanceInfos;
```

behind the sciences WPF is really doing somthing similar to

```
MaintenanceInfos.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(maintenanceInfos)
```

That function returns the same ColectionView for the same passed in `IEnumerable`, and the ColectionView holds information like [what the current selected item is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.currentitem(v=vs.110).aspx). I am not 100% sure, but I think the view also caches the underlying `IEnumerable` and only re-queries it if the view is notified via a event that the collection changed.

That is where your mystery caching is likely coming from, the same `ICollectionView` instance being returned from two [`GetDefaultView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview(v=vs.110).aspx) calls in the separate windows and it not re-querying the IEnumerable because it never received a collection changed event from the passed in object.

Comment: You are right.. Doing `var colsrc = new CollectionViewSource(); colsrc.Source = maintenanceInfos; MaintenanceInfos.ItemsSource = colsrc.View;` seems to be a way to circumvent the issue. I actually have a nested collection where the inner one is handled by binding, so that is a trickier one, but at least I have an idea of what's going now.. Thanks!

Comment: If you make the inner and outer collections a collection that implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) (For example [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)) that may solve your nesting issue. It all depends on what the type of `facade.MaintenanceInfos` really is if you can change the type out or not.